# Using COUNT and CONCAT together adding an extra row to results

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm currently taking the Google Data Analytics course and am very much a novice. It has us run a query from a public dataset to return the top 10 trips that people take with a public bike rental service. The query is as follows:

```
SELECT  
    usertype,
    CONCAT(start_station_name," to ",end_station_name) AS route,
    COUNT(*) AS num_trips,
    ROUND(AVG(cast(tripduration as int64)/60),2) AS duration
FROM 
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
GROUP BY   
    start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype
ORDER BY 
    num_trips DESC 
limit 10
```

This is the syntax from the course (maybe I made a mistake?), but my query does not return the same results. The results are supposed to be the top 10 trips by num_trips. What happens is I end up with a route named "to" that has a count of 5828994 and a duration of NULL [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYBaX.png) that returns as the top result.

I believe that the CONCAT and COUNT functions are interacting in a way that I am not familiar with, and CONCAT is creating an extra string of "to" that COUNT is then counting as a distinct route. How can I remove this result from the first row, or correct the syntax so that this result doesn't occur in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.  This is not an issue of `CONCAT()` or `GROUP BY`.  It is an issue with your data.  You have many rows where the start and end stations are not known, so they are empty string.

Perhaps you want to filter them out:

```
SELECT usertype,
       CONCAT(start_station_name, ' to ', end_station_name) AS route,
       COUNT(*) AS num_trips,
       ROUND(AVG(cast(tripduration as int64)/60),2) AS duration
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
WHERE start_station_name <> '' AND end_station_name <> ''
GROUP BY route, usertype
ORDER BY num_trips DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue too. Here is how I solved it with the help of a mentor:

You can avoid the first row empty cell by adding `WHERE tripduration IS NOT NULL`

Or:

Use the data from `bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_trips` to avoid the first row empty cell.

Hope this helps!